# Posting data to a iframe then download a file from a link

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe

I am having an issue with posting some data to an iframe then for it to download a file from a link.

I have searched stackoverflow for similar questions and have tried to adapt my code to make this work with the information i had found.

Currently it only posts the data to the iframe.

here is my code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="post" target="output_frame" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type='hidden' name='package_shape' value='box'  />
<input type="submit" name='op' id='go' value='download' />
</form>
<script>
    var downloadUrl = 'http://www.example.com/pdf';

    $('#myFrame').on('load', function(){
        console.log('WOOT!', arguments);
    });

    $('#go').on('click', function(){
        $('#myFrame').attr('src', downloadUrl);
    });
</script>
<iframe name="output_frame" src="" width="100%" height="500" id="myFrame">
</iframe>
```

If i created a button `<button id="go"/>Download</button>` and press it after the page has loaded within the iframe, it downloads the right file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send POST data to output URL, and also set downloadable URL:

```
$('#go').on('click', function(){
    $('#myFrame').on('load', function(){ $('#myFrame').attr('src', downloadUrl); } );
   //setTimeout( function(){ $('#myFrame').attr('src', downloadUrl); }, 500 );
});
```